# HTML 5 Canvas movement

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to put together a simple html game, and I'm running into a problem getting the character to jump. Everything works fine on all the movements, right left and down, but once I tried to call jump my screen freezes up and no action takes place. I;m probably listening something really simple, but I just can't seem to get it. I've also tried leaving out the draw/clear calls in the jump function and that hasn't worked either.

```
<script>
var isJumping = false;
var isFalling = false; 
var recwidth = 400;
var recheight = 400;
var xpos = 200;
var ypos = 200;
window.onload = function() {
var FPS = 30;
setInterval(function() {
  clear();
  draw();
}, 1000/FPS);
};
function jump()
 {
 isJumping=true;
 while (isJumping == true)
 {
    ypos=ypos-3;
    clear();
    draw();
    if(ypos==297)
    {
        isJumping == false;
    }

 }

 }



function changex(x){
xpos = xpos + (x);
}
function changey(y){
ypos = ypos + (y);
}



function draw(){
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
var  context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img=new Image()
    img.src="character.png"
    img.onload = function() { 
    context.drawImage(img,xpos,ypos)}
}

function clear(){
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
var  context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.clearRect(0,0,);
}


  document.onkeydown = function(event) {
var keyCode; 

if(event == null)
{
  keyCode = window.event.keyCode; 
}
else 
    {
 keyCode = event.keyCode; 
   }

   switch(keyCode)
   {
     // left 
     case 37:
    //left
    changex(-5);
       break; 

 // up 
 case 38:
 // action when pressing up key
 jump();
   break; 

 // right 
 case 39:
 // action when pressing right key
 changex(5);
  break; 

 // down
 case 40:
 // action when pressing down key
 changey(5);
   break; 

 default: 
   break; 
   } 
 }
```

Comment: Yes, you are not giving the processor time to breathe. This is normally done with setTimeout, since a while loop is too tight to do continuous screen updates

Comment: Ok that makes sense. So basically with a while loop it's trying to execute it too fast and that's causing an overload? So, then how would I execute multiple timeouts on it in succession?

Comment: Exactly. I am not sure how smooth things will be with setTimeout, but that is what is normally used. I found this with a loop animation canvas search http://www.script-tutorials.com/html5-animation-patterns-with-loops/

Comment: Alright, I'll do some experimenting with that, thanks!

Comment: Or setInterval and clearInterval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are not giving the processor time to breathe. This is normally done with setTimeout or setInterval since a while loop is too tight to do continuous screen updates

I am not sure how smooth things will be with setTimeout - I found this with a loop animation canvas search http://script-tutorials.com/html5-animation-patterns-with-loops